# Serializing with JAXB and the Any

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, apache-axis

I have a schema that defines the following type:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Payload">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And that creates an object like so:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Payload", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class Payload {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
}
```

Now I try adding another generated JAXB object to that Payload doing something like this:

```
Class payloadClass = ...;
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( WrapperRequest.class, payloadClass);
...
marshaller.marshal( wrappedRequest );
```

But I get a terrible exception that looks like it'll never work so I decide to serialize the payload object to XML first then add that as a string in the payload.

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( sdoRequest.getClass() );
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement(new QName("uri", sdoRequest.getClass().getSimpleName()), sdoRequest.getClass(), sdoRequest), writer);
payload.getAny().add( writer.toString() );
```

And this blows up with an exception saying "java.lang.String" does not contain an @XmlRootElement.

So how will the use of xs:any ever work with JAXB?  Nothing seems to want to work because JAXB turns the Payload into Object, and it won't serialize just anything in Object.  This is all inside Axis2 as well so it's been very challenging to get to this point.

Comment: What exception do you get when you try to add the wrapped object to the Any payload?

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Comment: This is partly how the WSDLs are put together which I have zero control over.  But, the wrapping request is defined in one WSDL and the request going in the payload is defined in another WSDL.  They both declare a BaseRequest, but when the code is generated they are different classes.  And I get this exception Two classes have the same XML type name {http://esp.lala.com/2012/eo}BaseRequest. Use @ XmlType.name and @ XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan The objected being added to the payload isn't annotated with @ XmlRootElement because it's generated from the WSDL.  What should I do?  What about the error I added?  See any easy way around that?

Comment: +one for "I get a terrible exception that looks like it'll never work"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Below I will demonstrate [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) and `any` with an example:

**Payload**

The `any` property is annotated with `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)`.  This means that for that property if an element is associated with a class via `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl` then an instance of the corresponding object will be used to populate the property if not the element will be set as an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

```
package forum13941747;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Payload", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class Payload {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;

}
```

**Foo**

Below is an example of a class annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.

```
package forum13941747;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

}
```

**Bar**

Below is an example of a class without the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.  In this use case we will leverage the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on a factory class (usually called `ObjectFactory`) annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

```
package forum13941747;

public class Bar {

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

Below is an example of specifying an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation for the `Bar` class.

```
package forum13941747;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="bar")
    public JAXBElement<Bar> createBar(Bar bar) {
        return new JAXBElement<Bar>(new QName("bar"), Bar.class, bar);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

Below is the input document we'll use for this example.  There are 3 elements that correspond to the `any` property.  The first corresponds to the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the `Foo` class.  The second corresponds to the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation for the `Bar` class and the third does not correspond to any of the domain classes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <foo/>
    <bar/>
    <other/>
</payload>
```

**Demo**

In the demo code below we will unmarshal the input document, then output the classes of the objects in the resulting `any` property and then marshal the `payload` object back to XML.

```
package forum13941747;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Payload.class, Foo.class, ObjectFactory.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum13941747/input.xml");
        Payload payload = (Payload) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        for(Object o : payload.any) {
            System.out.println(o.getClass());
        }

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(payload, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  Note the classes corresponding to the objects in the `any` property.  The `foo` element became an instance of the `Foo` class.  The `bar` element became an instance of `JAXBElement` that holds an instance of `Bar`.  The `other` element became an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

```xml
class forum13941747.Foo
class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<payload>
    <foo/>
    <bar/>
    <other/>
</payload>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Object Factory for mashelling the object like below you no need to have @XmlRootElement in DemoType.java .,

```
DemoType demoServiceRequest = new DemoType();
ObjectFactory obDemo = new ObjectFactory();  
Request requestObject = new Request();     
requestObject.setAny(obDemo.createDemo(demoServiceRequest));
```

And add DemoType class at Request.java like  @XmlSeeAlso({DemoType.class})

Answer (score 0):

Should your payload be a XML string, I managed to solve the very same problem using the code below:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

//...

String XMLPAYLOAD = "...";

Payload payload = new ObjectFactory().createPayload();
try {
    payload.setAny(DocumentBuilderFactory
           .newInstance()
           .newDocumentBuilder()
           .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XMLPAYLOAD)))
           .getDocumentElement());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//...
```