# Serializing with JAXB and the Any (without ElementNS)

Tags: jaxb

I'm looking a best practices to marshal a XMLAnyElement that can handle String, Long etc... I found a [Serializing with JAXB and the Any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941747/serializing-with-jaxb-and-the-any), but I need avoid ElementNS and resolve the case attached

Is DOMHandler the best way?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Payload.class, Foo.class, ObjectFactory.class);

    Payload payload = new Payload();
    payload.any = new ArrayList<>();
    payload.any.add(new Bar());
    payload.any.add(new Foo());
    payload.any.add("pepe"); 

    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(payload, System.out);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/franciscophilip/jaxb-payload-poc/

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, see my PoC on github..

https://github.com/franciscophilip/jaxb-payload-poc/